# Is this a safe use of unsafeCoerce?

Tags: haskell, types, dynamic-typing

I have a situation where I am at the moment using the extremely scary function unsafeCoerce. It's not for anything important fortunately, but I was wondering whether this seems to be a safe usage of this function, or whether there would be another way to solve this particular problem that other people know of.

The code I have is something like the following:

```
data Token b = Token !Integer

identical :: Token a -> Token b -> Bool
identical (Token a) (Token b) = a == b

data F a = forall b. F (Token b) (a -> b)

retrieve :: Token b -> F a -> Maybe (a -> b)
retrieve t (F t' f) = if identical t t' then Just (unsafeCoerce f) else Nothing
```

Two additional things to note, are that these tokens are used within a monad which I use to ensure that the supply of integers for them is unique (i.e. I don't make the same token twice). I also use a forall quantified shadow type variable, in the same way as the ST monad, to make sure that (assuming only the methods I expose in the module are used) there is no way to return a token (or in fact even an F) from the monad without it being a type error. I also don't expose the token constructor.

I think, as far as I can see, this should be a safe usage of unsafeCoerce, as I can say with (I hope) pretty high confidence that the value I am coercing is in fact of exactly the type that I am coercing it to, but I may be wrong. I have also tried using Data.Typeable, which works nicely, but at the moment I am trying this to avoid the Typeable constraint, especially as gcast seems to do something in many ways similar, and I would still need the tokens anyway to distinguish between different Fs of the same type.

Thanks very much for any help/advice.

Comment: This looks a lot like `Data.Typeable` which uses `unsafeCoerce` under the covers to implement `cast`.

Comment: It is a lot like that - in fact iirc I had said as much in the latter part of the last paragraph of the question. Thanks anyway.

Comment: If you're effectively copying `cast` then the usage of `unsafeCoerce` is safe but you do lose the compiler generated `typeOf`/`TypeRep`. You might consider using `TypeRep` instead of `Integer` in your token.

Comment: Well, the original reason was that I also need to distinguish two different values with the same type, but it may be neccessary to use Typeable/TypeRep as well then.

Answer (score 14):

You have implemented a restricted form of dynamic typing, broadly following the style of [Data.Dynamic](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/src/Data-Dynamic.html#Dynamic) -- namely, paring an (opaque) value with evidence of its type.
At runtime you can do an unsafe coercion, based on the evidence you shipped with the data.

```
fromDyn (Dynamic t v) def
  | typeOf def == t = unsafeCoerce v
  | otherwise       = def
```

This is the canoncial approach, with a long history, going back to:

> Mart´ın Abadi, Luca Cardelli, Benjamin Pierce, and Gordon Plotkin. Dynamic typing in a statically typed language.
>   ACM Transactions on Programming Languages and Systems,
>   13(2):237–268, April 1991.

The safety of the approach relies on the unforgeability of runtime type tokens. In your case, anyone can build a token that equates two types -- you would need to guarantee a 1-1 mapping from types to tokens, and ensure that a malicious user can't construct incorrect tokens. In the GHC case, we trust the Typeable instances (and module abstraction).

Answer (score 9):

It's not safe per se:

```
oops :: F Bool
oops = F (Token 12) not

bad :: Token Int
bad = Token 12

*Token> maybe 3 ($ True) $ retrieve bad oops
1077477808
```

`F a` is an existentially quantified type, you don't know what type `b` went into it. Since `identical` doesn't care about the type parameters to `Token`, it cannot check whether the supplied `b` from `retrieve`'s first argument has anything to do with what went into the `F a`.

Whether your protection

> Two additional things to note, are that these tokens are used within a monad which I use to ensure that the supply of integers for them is unique (i.e. I don't make the same token twice). I also use a forall quantified shadow type variable, in the same way as the ST monad, to make sure that (assuming only the methods I expose in the module are used) there is no way to return a token (or in fact even an F) from the monad without it being a type error. I also don't expose the token constructor.

is strong enough to make it safe in practice, I cannot tell without seeing it. If indeed no `Token`s can be created outside the computation, and the `Integer` value of the `Token` uniquely characterises the type parameter, it would be safe.