# Use of 'unsafeCoerce'

Tags: haskell, type-conversion, type-safety

In Haskell, there is a function called `unsafeCoerce`, that turns anything into any other type of thing. What exactly is this used for? Like, why we would you want to transform things into each other in such an "unsafe" way?

Provide an example of a way that `unsafeCoerce` is actually used. A link to Hackage would help. Example code in someones question would not.

Comment: It is usually only used when working with low-level types, such as when working with a C library or when doing some very deep type level magic.  99.9% of Haskellers should never use it.

Comment: @bheklilr Not a duplicate. His is a specific example.

Comment: It does provide an example, though.

Comment: @bheklilr Except that the answers go on to show that it is a poor example.

Comment: Reopening, as this is indeed more general than the [suggested question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14322311/2751851) (even if that is also a relevant example).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`unsafeCoerce` lets you convince the type system of whatever property you like. It's thus only "safe" exactly when you can be completely certain that the property you're declaring is true. So, for instance:

```
unsafeCoerce True :: Int
```

is a violation and can lead to wonky, bad runtime behavior.

```
unsafeCoerce (3 :: Int) :: Int
```

is (obviously) fine and will not lead to runtime misbehavior.

---

So what's a non-trivial use of `unsafeCoerce`? Let's say we've got an typeclass-bound existential type

```
module MyClass ( SomethingMyClass (..), intSomething ) where

class MyClass x where {}

instance MyClass Int where {}

data SomethingMyClass = forall a. MyClass a => SomethingMyClass a
```

Let's also say, as noted here, that the typeclass `MyClass` is *not exported* and thus nobody else can ever create instances of it. Indeed, `Int` is the only thing that instantiates it and the only thing that ever will.

Now when we pattern match to destruct a value of `SomethingMyClass` we'll be able to pull a "something" out from inside

```
foo :: SomethingMyClass -> ...
foo (SomethingMyClass a) =
  -- here we have a value `a` with type `exists a . MyClass a => a`
  --
  -- this is totally useless since `MyClass` doesn't even have any
  -- methods for us to use!
  ...
```

Now, at this point, as the comment suggests, the value we've pulled out has no type information—it's been "forgotten" by the existential context. It could be absolutely anything which instantiates `MyClass`.

Of course, in this *very particular* situation we know that the *only* thing implementing `MyClass` is `Int`. So our value `a` must *actually* have type `Int`. We could never convince the typechecker that this is true, but due to an outside proof we know that it is.

Therefore, we can (very carefully)

```
intSomething :: SomethingMyClass -> Int
intSomething (SomethingMyClass a) = unsafeCoerce a    -- shudder!
```

---

Now, hopefully I've suggested that this is a terrible, dangerous idea, but it also may give a taste of what kind of information we can take advantage of in order to know things that the typechecker cannot.

In non-pathological situations, this is rare. Even rarer is a situation where using something we know and the typechecker doesn't isn't itself pathological. In the above example, we must be completely certain that nobody ever extends our `MyClass` module to instantiate more types to `MyClass` otherwise our use of `unsafeCoerce` becomes instantly unsafe.

```
> instance MyClass Bool where {}
> intSomething (SomethingMyClass True)
6917529027658597398
```

Looks like our compiler internals are leaking!

---

A more common example where this sort of behavior might be valuable is when using `newtype` wrappers. It's a fairly common idea that we might wrap a type in a `newtype` wrapper in order to specialize its `instance` definitions.

For example, `Int` does not have a `Monoid` definition because there are two natural monoids over `Int`s: sums and products. Instead, we use `newtype` wrappers to be more explicit.

```
newtype Sum a = Sum { getSum :: a }

instance Num a => Monoid (Sum a) where
  mempty = Sum 0
  mappend (Sum a) (Sum b) = Sum (a+b)
```

Now, normally the compiler is pretty smart and recognizes that it can eliminate all of those `Sum` constructors in order to produce more efficient code. Sadly, there are times when it cannot, especially in highly polymorphic situations.

If you (a) know that some type `a` is actually just a newtype-wrapped `b` and (b) know that the compiler is incapable of deducing this itself, then you might want to do

```
unsafeCoerce (x :: a) :: b
```

for a slight efficiency gain. This, for instance, occurs frequently in `lens` and is expressed in the [`Data.Profunctor.Unsafe`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/profunctors-4.0.3/docs/Data-Profunctor-Unsafe.html) module of `profunctors`, a dependency of `lens`.

But let me again suggest that you really need to know what's going on before using `unsafeCoerce` like this is anything but highly unsafe.

---

One final thing to compare is the "typesafe `cast`" available in `Data.Typeable`. This function looks a bit like `unsafeCoerce`, but with much more ceremony.

```
unsafeCoerce ::                             a ->       b
cast         :: (Typeable a, Typeable b) => a -> Maybe b
```

Which, you might think of as being implemented using `unsafeCoerce` and a function `typeOf :: Typeable a => a -> TypeRep` where `TypeRep` are unforgeable, runtime tokens which reflect the type of a value. Then we have

```
cast :: (Typeable a, Typeable b) => a -> Maybe b
cast a = if (typeOf a == typeOf b) then Just b else Nothing 
  where b = unsafeCoerce a
```

Thus, `cast` is able to ensure that the types of `a` and `b` *really are* the same at runtime, and it can decide to return `Nothing` if they are not. As an example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable        #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}

data A = A deriving (Show, Typeable)
data B = B deriving (Show, Typeable)

data Forget = forall a . Typeable a => Forget a

getAnA :: Forget -> Maybe A
getAnA (Forget something) = cast something
```

which we can run as follows

```
> getAnA (Forget A)
Just A
> getAnA (Forget B)
Nothing
```

---

So if we compare this usage of `cast` with `unsafeCoerce` we see that it can achieve some of the same functionality. In particular, it allows us to rediscover information that may have been forgotten by `ExistentialQuantification`. However, `cast` manually checks the types at runtime to ensure that they are truly the same and thus cannot be used unsafely. To do this, it demands that both the source and target types allow for runtime reflection of their types via the `Typeable` class.

Comment: May I suggest adding `Data.Coerce.Coercible (coerce)` to this answer?

Comment: For those wondering, [`unsafeCoerce`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Unsafe-Coerce.html#v:unsafeCoerce) and [`coerce`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Coerce.html#v:coerce) perform the same operation: literally nothing. They only change the type `a -> b` except `coerce` is safe by constraining them to have identical representation `Coercible a b => a -> b`

Answer (score 7):

The only time I ever felt compelled to use `unsafeCoerce` was on finite natural numbers.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, GADTs, TypeFamilies, StandaloneDeriving #-}

data Nat = Z | S Nat deriving (Eq, Show)

data Fin (n :: Nat) :: * where
    FZ :: Fin (S n)
    FS :: Fin n -> Fin (S n)

deriving instance Show (Fin n)
```

`Fin n` is a singly linked data structure that is statically ensured to be smaller than the `n` type level natural number by which it is parametrized.

```
-- OK, 1 < 2 
validFin :: Fin (S (S Z))
validFin = FS FZ

-- type error, 2 < 2 is false
invalidFin :: Fin (S (S Z))
invalidFin = FS (FS FZ)
```

`Fin` can be used to safely index into various data structures. It's pretty standard in dependently typed languages, though not in Haskell.

Sometimes we want to convert a value of `Fin n` to `Fin m` where `m` is greater than `n`.

```
relaxFin :: Fin n -> Fin (S n)
relaxFin FZ     = FZ
relaxFin (FS n) = FS (relaxFin n)
```

`relaxFin` is a no-op by definition, but traversing the value is still required for the types to check out. So we might just use `unsafeCoerce` instead of `relaxFin`. More pronounced gains in speed can result from coercing larger data structures that contain `Fin`-s  (for example, you could have lambda terms with `Fin`-s as bound variables).

This is an admittedly exotic example, but I find it interesting in the sense that it's pretty safe: I can't really think of ways for external libraries or safe user code to mess this up. I might be wrong though and I'd be eager to hear about potential safety issues.

Answer (score 2):

There is no use of `unsafeCoerce` I can really recommend, but I can see that in some cases such a thing might be useful.

The first use that springs to mind is the implementation of the `Typeable`-related routines. In particular `cast :: (Typeable a, Typeable b) => a -> Maybe b` achieves a type-safe behaviour, so it is safe to use, yet it has to play dirty tricks in its implementation.

Maybe `unsafeCoerce` can find some use when importing FFI subroutines to force types to match. After all, FFI already allows to import impure C functions as pure ones, so it is intrinsecally usafe. Note that "unsafe" does not mean impossible to use, but just "putting the burden of proof on the programmer".

Finally, pretend that `sortBy` did not exist. Consider then this example:

```
-- Like Int, but using the opposite ordering
newtype Rev = Rev { unRev :: Int }
instance Ord Rev where compare (Rev x) (Rev y) = compare y x

sortDescending :: [Int] -> [Int]
sortDescending =  map unRev . sort . map Rev
```

The code above works, but feels silly IMHO. We perform two `map`s using functions such as `Rev,unRev` which we *know* to be no-ops at runtime. So we just scan the list twice for no reason, but that of convincing the compiler to use the right `Ord` instance.

The performance impact of these maps should be small since we also sort the list. Yet it is tempting to rewrite `map Rev` as `unsafeCoerce :: [Int]->[Rev]` and save some time.

Note that having a coercing function

```
castNewtype :: IsNewtype t1 t2 => f t2 -> f t1
```

where the constraint means that `t1` is a newtype for `t2` would help, but it would be quite dangerous. Consider

```
castNewtype :: Data.Set Int -> Data.Set Rev
```

The above would cause the data structure invariant to break, since we are changing the ordering underneath! Since `Data.Set` is implemented as a binary search tree, it would cause quite a large damage.

Comment: This last bit, the `IsNewtype` class, is being implemented in GHC 7.8 as [`Coercible`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.8.1-rc1/html/libraries/base-4.7.0.0/GHC-Exts.html#t%3ACoercible). In order to solve the invariant problem you've stated there's also a [Role Annotation](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.8.1-rc1/html/users_guide/roles.html) system being implemented which allows library writers to define whether or not a type should be Coercible. This also patches a long-standing bug in `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving`.